# SVG text in path element

Tags: vector, svg

I have svg map, but without any markings.
But I want to states were designated by letters.
Is there any possibility do it?
Text or tooltips, any marks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can place text at specific coordinates, e.g.:

```
<text x="0" y="20" font-size="1em" fill="red">XY</text>
```